# How to play .mkv files in 9.10

Tags: video, 9.10

I am using Ubuntu 9.10. Recently I had convert my pendrive from FAT32 to NTFS format to save mkv files. Then when I insert and play it in Ubuntu it doesn't play. The following error occurs:

> The required software to play this file is not installed. The playback software MPEG-4 AAC decoder is required.

How can I get, install and play it on Ubuntu 9.10?

Comment: Flagged off-topic because 9.10 was EOL 1 year before this question was asked.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the codec to allow your video program to understand MPEG-4 AAC audio. The Ubuntu site doesn't have the 9.10 Karmic packages listed anymore, but it is probably the same as in 10.04 Lucid.

So, you need to install the [faad codec and tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/sound/faad) which are in the *universe* repository.

You could try using a terminal program and typing

```
sudo apt-get install faad libfaad2
```

If that doesn't help, let us know what video program you are using.

For the ubuntu movie player, this might help http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1214139

Or this is for VLC, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1279156